# android backup single folder once it's updated

Tags: android, apk, backup

**hello mates,**

i want to ask if there's an android app that can backup a single folder in storage once the folder is updated fully automatically, i mean if i added a picture or file in a folder i want it to be checked and backed up automatically without any user interference

is there an app already out there that can do this and if i should create one would it be a script that i can put it in init folder or an apk

sorry for the newbie question guys

Answer (score 0):

Write a service to constantly check a folder size. Below code is to check the folder size. Attach this to a service which will execute this code based on events or whatever how you need

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class PathSize 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get(".");
        long size = calculateSize(path);
        System.out.println(size);
    }
    public static long calculateSize(Path path) {
        try {
            if (Files.isRegularFile(path)) {
                return Files.size(path);
            }

            return Files.list(path).mapToLong(PathSize::calculateSize).sum();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return 0L;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i am not an Android Developer so could u clarify this more please

Comment: U need a service to make the process in automation. you i will be having code to check the folder size and to run your service. Service will execute your backup code in specific instance of time. if the folder has been filled with data then it will do backup. if not ,then it will scan the folder until it size varies. This is how you want to perform the process

Comment: thanks for the help so far i started learning java and android so i can catch up but 1 more questiong please
i want the service to
1)check for change every 1 min
2) copy the content to new folder lets say /storage/sdcard0/backupfolder

how can i make those 2 functions and where to put them in your code and where is the path of the checked folder in your code lets say its /storage/sdcard0/checkedfolder